# Clear cache for end users Weebly

Tags: javascript, html, caching, browser-cache, weebly

I have a website hosted on Weebly. It looks fine right now.

However, when people first visited the website, caching was enabled.
Thus when they visit the website in the future it still looks like the first draft of the website.
I added meta-tags that disable caching (just for while the website is still being built, I will enable some type of caching in the future). Now if you visit the website, changes will be seen/loaded right away.
The issue is, anyone who visited the website previously is seeing a very old cached version. It doesn't actually reload the new website that has the meta-tags that disable caching.

I can't upload a fix because:

1. Javascript is not allowed to clear a cache. (hard reload does not fix this)
2. Any fix, like disabling caching with meta-tags, won't get loaded
   because the website is using the cached version without the fix.
3. I cannot change the name of index.html (weebly doesn't allow this)

I know I can clear my cache to fix the issue on my browser. But any other user who has already visited the site doesn't know to do that.

I tried to look at when the cache for files would expire. Some files expire next year (which is too long to wait). Others don't have an expiration date at all.

I have looked online and tried the solutions, but none seem to fix this specific issue.

Comment: _...still looks like the first draft of the website..._ Do you mean just the css or any functionalities as well?

Comment: Everything, Javascript, CSS, and HTML. If I add new HTML text or CSS styling, non of it changes.